# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I am uploading an Excel sheet using ajax and inserting the data into the database. I tested and it's working.

But I am getting an error in the network tab.

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/assets/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php
> on line 1934

I have only 1 record in the Excel sheet and when I import the sheet then I am getting three rows (the first row is correct and the remaining two rows are NULL).

I am using the below code

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="import_excelsheet" name="import_excelsheet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group"><input type="file" name="list21" /></div>
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="list21Import">
 <input type="submit" name="listImport21" id="list_import" class="btn btn-primary" value="Import list" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#import_excelsheet').validate({
    rules: {
        list21: {
            required: true,
            extension: "xlsx|xls|xlsm|csv"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        list21: {
            required: "file .xlsx, .xlsm, .xls, .csv only.",
            extension: "Please upload valid file formats .xlsx, .xlsm, .xls, .csv only."
        }
    },

submitHandler: function(form) {  
      $.ajax({
      url:"process.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:new FormData($('#import_excelsheet')[0]),
      contentType:false,
      cache:false,
      processData:false,
      success:function(data)
      {
        alert("success");
        //location.reload();
      }
    }) ;    
         }
});
```

**Process.php** (this is just a function)

```
function list21Import($pdo){
if($_FILES["list21"]["name"] != '')
{
         $allowed_extension = array('xls', 'csv', 'xlsx');
         $file_array = explode(".", $_FILES["list21"]["name"]);
         $file_extension = end($file_array);

         if(in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension))
         {
          $file_name = time() . '.' . $file_extension;
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['list21']['tmp_name'], $file_name);
          $file_type = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($file_name);
          $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($file_type);

          $spreadsheet = $reader->load($file_name);

          unlink($file_name);

          $data = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
          //print_r($data);
         
          $isheader = 0;
          foreach($data as $row)
          {

            $social['fb'] = trim($row[5]);
            $social['twitter'] = trim($row[6]);
            $social['linkedin'] = trim($row[7]);
            $social['youtube'] = trim($row[8]);
            $social['instagram'] = trim($row[9]);
            $social_links = serialize($social);

          if($isheader > 0) {
           $insert_data = array(
            ':name'  => $row[0],
            ':email'  => $row[1],
            ':content'  => $row[2],
            ':website'  => $row[3],
            ':logo'  => $row[4],
            ':social_links'  =>$social_links,
           );

           $query = "INSERT INTO `list21`(`name`, `email`, `content`, `website`, `logo`, `social_links`) VALUES (:name,:email,:content,:website,:logo,:social_links)";
           $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
           $statement->execute($insert_data);

           } 
           else { 
            $isheader = 1; 
           }

          } // foreach
          $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Data Imported Successfully</div>';

         } //in_array

         else
         {
          $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .xls .csv or .xlsx file allowed</div>';
         }

}
else
{
 $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please Select File</div>';
}

echo $message;

}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: For a start, you're making the assumption that the spreadsheet can't possibly not have all the required columns.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, a little bit confused here. Can you help me in detail? Because I tried my code and it's working but also getting error

Comment: `$social['fb'] = trim($row[5]);` - What if `$row` only has 3 columns?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, Actually, what I am doing is, I have excel sheet column format.. I mean I added all the columns(which is in the first row) and the admin can insert manually all the columns or can be empty. Then admin can upload the excel sheet.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have a column in the database called social_link and in the excel sheet I have FB,Twitter, Instagram, linked In, youtube (5 columns) and I am inserting it into the database using serialize. is this the correct way?

Comment: Is that another question? Your DB engine will not complaint but please note that, being strict, `serialize()` can return binary data so you'd ideally need a binary column type. Also, storing unstructured information in a relational database makes it difficult to do simple stuff like searching.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, Can you share any link or any example where I can learn this?